# Nextjs project where the client gets SSE from a Node application. Shared database or not?

Tags: next.js, architecture, serverless, server-sent-events

I'm working on a web application where SEO is crucial, and there's a need for live data using Server-Sent Events (SSE). I've chosen Next.js because i'm well versed with react but due to serverless limitations, I plan to also create an API using Node.js to handle SSE, as well as CRUD requests for entity management so that most of the times that the client will need to fetch or send some data he will directly communicate with the API instead of the Next.js server.

My intention is to have Next.js communicate with the database only for user authentication (using Auth.js, because of provider login mostly, with JWT) and have the Node.js API verify these JWTs with a shared JWT_SECRET. This way, when a client sends a request to the API, he can be authenticated, and data related to the user included in the JWT can be returned.

That said it seems to me that Next.js and the API should share the same database. Is this approach considered a bad practice? Should i handle login-register in the API as well? Is there something similar to Auth.js for Node meaning a package that can handle all of the backend part of the provider authentication logic?